# Is there a way to select the ColName when the field = 1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been playing around with a few SQL queries trying to get the column name when the field from the row is equal to `1`.

My table looks like this:

```
user  | col 1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4 |
user1 |    1  |    1  |     0 |    1  |
user2 |    0  |    1  |     1 |    1  |
user3 |    1  |    0  |     0 |    1  |
```

I'm trying to get each column name to display for when each value is equal to `1`.

```
SELECT ColNames
FROM table
WHERE user1 = 1
```

Comment: That's not really how databases work. Is your table some sort of permissions or settings table or something like that?

Comment: Similar, its a table filled in via a tick box form depending on whether they have an item.  Perhaps re-designing my table is required?

Comment: yes, indeed. It looks like you have an m-by-n matrix going on, which means you should have three tables. One for your users, one for the items, and one to indicate which users have which items (often called the "junction table" or "join table" or "association table").

Comment: Got a quick example on how that query might look, thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean only show column names where the value is 1 for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above, you need three tables. One for users, one for items, and one that joins the two. Here's the structure and queries that I use for a similar function, maintaining user defined mailing lists:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_listmembers` (
`listmem_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`list_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,


CREATE TABLE `tbl_lists` (
`list_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`list_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`list_description` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,


CREATE TABLE `tbl_user_accounts` (
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `user_last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
```

And the query that pulls up members from a particular list:

```
SELECT lm.list_id, lm.user_id, ua.user_first_name, ua.user_last_name, ua.user_id
FROM test.tbl_listmembers AS lm 
LEFT JOIN test.tbl_user_accounts AS ua ON (ua.user_id = lm.user_id)
WHERE (lm.list_id = combo_box_selected_listnumber)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cheers, thats a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Normalize your database!

```
user  | n | value
user1 | 1 | 1
user1 | 2 | 1
user1 | 3 | 0
user1 | 4 | 1
user2 | 1 | 0 
user2 | 2 | 1
user2 | 3 | 1 
user2 | 4 | 1 
user3 | 1 | 1 
user3 | 2 | 0 
user3 | 3 | 0
user3 | 4 | 1
```

Now it's easy!

```
SELECT n
FROM users
WHERE user = 'user1' AND value = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
select case when col1=1 then 'Col 1' else '' end +
    case when col2=1 then 'Col 2' else '' end + 
    case when col3=1 then 'Col 3' else '' end + 
    case when col4=1 then 'Col 4' else '' end 
from users
where user = 'user1'
```

EDIT: oops, this is for transact SQL, not sure if mysql has the same `case` construct, if not, my bad

Comment: MySQL has CASE, which I think is ANSI SQL-92 standard.